# Golang UnmarshalTypeError missing Offset

Tags: json, go, error-handling

I'm totally newbie in Golang and solving problem with parsing JSON. Everything is working, except error handling.

```
if err := json.Unmarshal(file, &configData); err != nil {    
    if ute, ok := err.(*json.UnmarshalTypeError); ok {
        fmt.Printf("UnmarshalTypeError %v - %v - %v", ute.Value, ute.Type, ute.Offset)        
    }
}
```

Here I get error `ute.Offset undefined (type *json.UnmarshalTypeError has no field or method Offset)` but in [Docs of JSON package](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#UnmarshalTypeError) and also [code](https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/decode.go?s=3363:3613#L89) they have this variable in `UnmarshalTypeError` struct.

What I'm doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: what version of Go are you using?

Comment: `UnmarshalTypeError.Offset` was added in Go 1.5: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/api/go1.5.txt#L286

Comment: That is the problem. I have 1.2.1, but don't know why. Installed on Ubuntu14.04 with apt-get just yesterday..

Comment: @Arxeiss never install go with apt-get for serious work,

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer I found this https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Ubuntu so I thought that it is OK...

Comment: @Arxeiss the binary packages on the golang website work great and are super easy to set up. If you want to remain with current go versions, stick with them.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer I'm not saying that I want to stuck at old version. I just said, where I found it. So maybe I should say it again. I found it on that link, so I thought that it is OK. Why I shouldn't use apt-get, if in original golang reposiroty they are suggesting it? And why in apt-get repositories are so old versions?

Comment: @Arxeiss Ubuntu repositories do not change the version of a piece of software during the lifetime of an Ubuntu version. 14.04 is almost two years old, and uses the the recent Go version for that time. Unless there's an apt repo that publishes up to date Go versions somewhere, you are stuck with only minor version updates for a certain version.

Answer (score 3):

According to the godoc description:

> If a JSON value is not appropriate for a given target type, or if a JSON number overflows the target type, Unmarshal skips that field and completes the unmarshalling as best it can. If no more serious errors are encountered, Unmarshal returns an UnmarshalTypeError describing the earliest such error.

Just like `string` type unmarshals into `chan` type,it make a `UnmarshalTypeError` error,just like the following:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type A struct {
    Name string
    Chan chan int
}

func main() {
    var a A
    bs := []byte(`{"Name":"hello","Chan":"chan"}`)
    if e := json.Unmarshal(bs, &a); e != nil {
        if ute, ok := e.(*json.UnmarshalTypeError); ok {
            fmt.Printf("UnmarshalTypeError %v - %v - %v\n", ute.Value, ute.Type, ute.Offset)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Other error:", e)
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
UnmarshalTypeError string - chan int - 29
```

It is working properly!

Comment: Problem is older version of Golang in my case.. Check comments under my post